# Webview get focus automatically when removing URL from Edit Text

Tags: android, webview

I have one Edit Text, 5 buttons and a Webview. Webview load url when user type url in edit text and tap Go button or hit Enter on soft keyboard.
I have three problems here.

1-WebView loads website for example "www.google.com" but soft keyboard does not hide itself. I want to hide it like other browser do.

2-When user open a specific url and then try to remove it from Edit Text to open a different url, webview start loading that incomplete url and get focus automatically on every letter removing. For example user loads "www.google.com" then he try to remove url from end and as he remove "m", webview try to load "www.google.co" then edit text is out of focus and webview stole focus from it then user have to tap in edit text again to remove url but it tries to load after every letter removing. I need Webview to load url only when user tap on Go button or hit Enter on soft keyboard.

**Update** (forgot to add third problem, here it is)

3-Where can i check when WebView CanGoBack and CanGoForward because i want to set visibility of Back and Forward buttons to false at startup and enabled these two buttons while they CanGoBack and CanGoForward. Where should i put my piece of code to check these conditions?

I hope you guys can understand what i am trying to say. Sorry for my poor english.

Here is my xml code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="13"
    tools:context="com.hbss.chatapp.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.rashidfaheem.youseebrowser.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4"
        >


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etUrl"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="GO"
            android:id="@+id/btnGo"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Back"
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Forward"
            android:id="@+id/btnForward"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reload"
            android:id="@+id/btnReload"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="11"
    >
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wb"
        />


</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText etUrl;
Button btnGo, btnBack, btnForward, btnClear, btnReload;
WebView wb;
String url;
View v;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wb.setWebViewClient(new ourClient());



    etUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUrl);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnForward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnReload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReload);

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnReload.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

    etUrl.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && i==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                return true;
            }
            load();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnGo:
            load();
            break;
        case R.id.btnBack:
            if (wb.canGoBack())
                wb.goBack();
            break;
        case R.id.btnForward:
            if (wb.canGoForward())
                wb.goForward();
            break;
        case R.id.btnReload:
            wb.reload();
            break;
        case R.id.btnClear:
            wb.clearHistory();
            break;
    }
}

    public void load(){
    url = etUrl.getText().toString();
    if (!url.startsWith("http://")) {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }
    try {
        wb.loadUrl(url);
        wb.requestFocus();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add third problem, added it now in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this method to hide the keyboard:

```
 public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity context) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputManager != null)
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getWindow()
                .getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
    context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

}
```

call it in your `load()` method like:

```
hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
```

For your **second** question you need to call your method inside the condition like:

```
etUrl.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if ((keyEvent.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (i==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
            load();  //add it here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

For the `webview` go back feature: override `onKeyDown` in your activity and check condition like:

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wb.canGoBack()) {
        wb.goBack();
        //show your back button here
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    //show other buttons
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

You can add the check in your `onResume()` and `load()` also and show your button accordingly..

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
     if(wb.canGoBack()){
        //show back button}
    else{
        //other button
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanx bro. BTW, is it okay to use these three line code to hide keyboard. View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);

Comment: Really appreciated bro. Can you answer my third problem which i forgot to add before, updated my answer just now.

Comment: Rafsan Ahmad bro, I just did what you told regarding GoBack method but this onKeyDown method excutes only when user press Back button (hard button on his cell). I want to enable my Back button when there is possible to go back. As mozilla firefox provide. User open firefox and open a url for example "www.google.com" and when google page loads, Back button of firefox near address bar get enabled. Where should i can check this condition?

Comment: yes i understand you can add the check in your `load()` and `onResume()`..method : `if(wb.canGoBack()){
    //show back button}
else{
    //other button
    }`

Comment: Hey bro, sorry to bother you but another innocent question came up. How to add progress bar in this WebView project? Many example i have seen regarding including progressbar with Webview, almost all creating a webviewclient class (class which extends webviewclient) inside MainActivity class but when i do it, it says "class MyClient is public, should be declared in file named "MyClient.java" thats why i need to create this in another file so i can't access progressbar which in declared and initialized in MainActivity.

Comment: How can i change that progressbar through my external "MyClient" class using onPageStarted and onPageFinished methods?

Comment: it will be better if u ask a new question ....so that everybody can help...the context of this question is already anwered