# Webview doesn't scroll down after keyboard dimiss

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-webview

I am loading URL into webview. Webpage has text input field at bottom, so when start typing into that scrolling works fine. But after dismiss keyboard, webview content doesn't scroll at bottom again.

I tried with different windowSoftInputMode but none of them works for me.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode
```

Please help me on this. 
I know there are many similar questions like this one but none of them works for me so i am creating this separate thread.

Comment: I think the WebView loses its focus. Do u lose focus to close keyboard ?

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru Yes but it is working fine while i start typing, but once i dismiss keyboard then webview keeps on same position instead of scroll to original position.

Comment: Do you mean it isn't scrolling at all ?

Comment: try to close keyboard as exlained here this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: No it is scrolling up when i start typing but after dismiss of keyboard it doesn't scroll bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link , As web view is not clear the focus even after keyboard hide.
[Webview get focus automatically when removing URL from Edit Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710772/webview-get-focus-automatically-when-removing-url-from-edit-text)